# Pipeline and electric power grid data for Southern California?

Tags: data, united-states, utility-network

Does anyone know where I can find GIS shapefile or other data for the electric transmission line system as well as water/natural gas and other pipeline systems for Southern California? Notably San Diego county?

Comment: That data is likely to be protected by the owners of those utilities. If you have a genuine reason contact them and request a clip of the data.

Comment: Never mind the owners, post 9-11 critical infrastructure like that is nowhere near as widely available as it once was. In many cases you need to provide identification in order to access the data, if you can at all. Your best bet is probably to contact the county and see if they have reference layers you would be able to use for whatever your need is.